# Visual Studio c# open console from windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console

I have a visual studio project in c#, And i'd like to be able to launch console applications from my windows form. For example, launching a console window/program on a button press event. I know it is possible to launch form applications from console using the application.run(Form) method, but id like to per say launch the following program in a new console window on a button press event, and be able to send and receive data between the windows forms, and the console window.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a console application from a windows Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275403/run-a-console-application-from-a-windows-form)

Comment: Do you want to open a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) or a console like Console Application does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is easy. To run a program, *any* program, from C#, just use [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Process.Start("myApp.exe");
```

The second is *much* more complicated. You have started an actual *process*, so you can't just "communicate" with it. You need to do some IPC (Inter-Process Communication). How you do so is up to you, but named pipes and WCF are both good options.