# How to call a class from a winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, console

Sorry I use this title on purpose. I m quite new on c# and i don't manage to call my class on the usual way.

I have a winform and I want to insert a class (copy and paste from an API), and call it from my winform.

This class is a program which open the console, ask me parameters and then lunch an EMG acquisition.

the class is like that:

```
  class Program1     
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            { 
// some code here, with  a lot of "Console.Writeline"
            }
        }
```

It works fine.

I change it to:

```
  public class Program1     
            {
               public void method1(string[] args)
                { 
//some code here, , with  a lot of "Console.Writeline"
                }
            }
```

And i tried to call it on my form

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Program1 program = new Program1();
            program.method1();
        }
```

it says "No overload for method 'method1' takes 0 arguments" . 
The thing i don"t understand is when i run the program of the API alone it doesn't ask me anything it just runs.

I'm pretty sure the error is from the `Console.WriteLine` and `Console.Readline` but i don't know how to resolve my problem. 
I want a button on my winform which run my class, open the console and ask me on the console which paramaters i want.

Thank you !

Comment: dont forget "string[] args", your input is not void. "program.method1(new string[] {"a","b","c"});"

Comment: This is a problem because, even if you call the method, you don't have a console because you're running a winforms application.

Comment: Ok the program runs now (thank you) ! But nothing happens, it just freezes!!

Comment: You can't call a console on a winform?! Why not?!

Comment: Why don't you build the code into your WinForms application? Does it have to run in a console?

Comment: You can, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593313/how-to-execute-console-application-from-windows-form) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275403/run-a-console-application-from-a-windows-form)

Comment: `"No overload for method 'method1' takes 0 arguments"` -- the error tells you exactly the problem. You're calling the method as if it has an overload that takes 0 arguments, but there is no such overload. It works when you run the program because the runtime _passes an argument_! I.e. it doesn't try to do the invalid thing you are trying to do. It sounds like you just want to run the program as a separate process (i.e. with a console window, per the links from Mong's comment), but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @DominikB I wanted to do it like that first, but the API is for experienced programmer and modify it is quite complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Method overloading is a feature in OOP. which allow you to write multiple methods of the same name but with the different parameters, during invocation it pick the correct one  by the parameters.***

> You can try

***passing the specified parameters which is `string[] args` as eg.***

```
public class Program1     
{
    public void method1(string[] args){ 
        //some code here, , with  a lot of "Console.Writeline"
    }
}
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Program1 program = new Program1();
    program.method1(new string[]{"one","two"});
}
```

***Or Try with optional parameters as eg.***

```
public class Program1     
{
    public void method1(string[] args=null){ 
        //some code here, , with  a lot of "Console.Writeline"
    }
}
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Program1 program = new Program1();
    program.method1();
}
```

Comment: He could also use a paramless method `public void method1()`

Comment: Yes actually worfs fine, thank you! I don't get why  they put (string[] args) then..